# can php adodb do Common Table Expressions?

Tags: php, adodb, common-table-expression

I'm using the adodb php library (http://phplens.com/adodb/) to connect to sql server 2005, can Common Table Expressions be used in the execute method?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I first have to figure out how to write a cte, but if I can't issue it with the adodb php library then it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the SQL is passed through without modifications (which I assume it does) you'll be able to use CTEs, yes.

A simple test could be something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM mytable
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```